# how could i identify that alexa notification is being seen(heard) by the user?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to push notifications to my Alexa Device until the recent notification is seen by the user. If the user has seen the notification I should stop sending it. If the customer hasn't seen my recent notification I should keep on sending the notifications until they have seen it.

So I need to identify whether my notification has been seen by the user or not.

Is there any service or API that could fetch me whether the delivered notification is seen by the user or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, [Proactive Events](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/proactive-events-api.html) are one-way and not bidirectional: you send a notification to the user, the user can read it but there is no way to know if the user has read the notification.